# changes on css file doesn't take effect on the browser

Tags: css, html

I have a `css` file which will style a form element in my  **register.php**
page.I have modified the css file .But changes i made doesn't take effect. Here i changed the height of the body from `1500 px` to `auto`. But changes i made don't appear on actual page.It remained `1500 px`. How can i solve this?

> Browser view-source:

[image]

> Code from IDE

[image]

Comment: Add Codes in to your post instead of screenshot. We cannot view whole code with just screenshot

Comment: use ctrl+f5 .. may be your css file is cached

Answer (score 1):

You may need to put `body { height:auto !important; }` as there may be a declaration somewhere else that is overriding it.